# Share via (facebook, twitter...) on Android Phonegap APP

Tags: android, html, cordova, share, sharekit

I'm searching a plugin like "**ShareKit for Iphone phonegap App**" (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/ShareKitPlugin) 
that we can to choose some service from a window to post some content from an app.

I try the "Share plugin" (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Share) 
 but I only can send to an e-mail and not facebook and twitter..

Anybody can help me about this? Thanks!

sorry for my bad english! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Share

I believe this uses the sharing in Android (i.e.: you can share to any appropriate installed app).

Comment: I tested this plugin with Android Emulator in my PC, but only I can send by e-mail. If I install apps like Facebook or Twitter I'll can share with these?

Comment: THANKS @Devgeeks !! I try with some socialnetworks apps installed and I can share with these!!!

:)

Comment: The answer *is* 2 years old. Plugins from that repo would no longer be relevant with Cordova/PhoneGap 3.x+. However, for reference: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/DEPRECATED/Android/Share